# Angular routerLink relative navigation without matrix parameters

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

When I navigate to a child component via `routerLink` directive, the parent component matrix parameters are kept in the url. For example, if the url is `localhost/parent;arg=1`, and the routerLink looks like:

```
<a routerLink="child"></a>
```

The child url will be `localhost/parent;arg=1/child`, but I want to leave out matrix parameters while navigation. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I found in [routerLink description](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description), you can just add an empty matrix parameters `{}` to beginning of the route. Because, in my case, the route doesn't have a prefix (which means that the route starts from the current activated route), the parent parameters will be replaced by empty ones.

```
<a [routerLink]="[{}, 'child']"></a>
```